# Geocoding using Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

At the moment I use a latlang to specify the location:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.097303, 0.275820);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 15,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var contentString = '<div id="bubbleContent">'+'<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"  width="200" height="35"/>'
'</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString,
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng, 
  map: map, 
}); 
infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
</script>
```

How do I use geocoding to use an address instead? e.g. Cambridge, United Kingdom

Thanks

Comment: This has been answered in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213147/using-google-api-gclientgeocoder

Answer (score -3, accepted):

var map;
var geocoder;
var address;

function initialize() {
  map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40.730885,-73.997383), 15);
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl);
  GEvent.addListener(map, "click", getAddress);
  geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
}

function getAddress(overlay, latlng) {
  if (latlng != null) {
    address = latlng;
    geocoder.getLocations(latlng, showAddress);
  }
}

function showAddress(response) {
  map.clearOverlays();
  if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
    alert("Status Code:" + response.Status.code);
  } else {
    place = response.Placemark[0];
    point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],place.Point.coordinates[0]);
    marker = new GMarker(point);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(
        '>b<orig latlng:>/b<' + response.name + '>br/<' + 
        '>b<latlng:>/b<' + place.Point.coordinates[1] + "," + place.Point.coordinates[0] + '>br<' +
        '>b<Status Code:>/b<' + response.Status.code + '>br<' +
        '>b<Status Request:>/b<' + response.Status.request + '>br<' +
        '>b<Address:>/b<' + place.address + '>br<' +
        '>b<Accuracy:>/b<' + place.AddressDetails.Accuracy + '>br>' +
        '>b>Country code:>/b< ' + place.AddressDetails.Country.CountryNameCode);
  }
}

Comment: The question is how to use geocoding with Api v3, not Api v2.