# Using Google API - GClientGeocoder()

Tags: api, google-maps

I try to follow this page:

```
http://melandri.net/2009/07/03/get-location-coordinates-using-google-maps/
```

but GClientGeocoder() is not defined - there is an error.

I already us the google maps api on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%=System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myGoogleKey"]%>&sensor=false"></script>
```

How to resolve my error?

Here is how I succesfuly use the API:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`GClientGeocoder()` is a Version 2 object. You are loading the Version 3 API and need to use Version 3 objects and methods.

The Version 3 equivalent is `google.maps.Geocoder()` and is described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding). It's not the same as the Version 2 implementation.